# Trying to understand TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to get a PDF document from PHP. So far it is working fine, but now I am fighting at this point:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $nombre_plato ="";
  $nombre_plato .=  "  ".recuperar_nombre_plato($row['plato_pedido'])."";

  $pdf->writeHTML($nombre_plato, true, 0, true, 0);
}
```

recuperar_nombre_plato($variable) is a function called from another file.

If I write:

```
$nombre_plato .=  "  ".$row['plato_pedido']."";
```

then, the output is as expected ($row['plato_pedido']=1), there are 4 rows:

[image]

But using the desired code

```
$nombre_plato .=  "  ".recuperar_nombre_plato($row['plato_pedido'])."";
```

the output is a blank space, no output.
The function works fine on other files.The output string is shown on other files, but not here.

Any help is welcome...

EDIT:

```
function recuperar_nombre_plato ($recibido) {

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'XXX';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'XXX';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'XXX';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXX", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_platos WHERE id_plato = '".$recibido."'";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        return $row['nombre_plato'];
        }


    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }


}
```

COMPLETE SOURCE CODE:

```
<?php session_start();
include "funciones.php"; 
include "definiciones.php";
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Dario Balas');
$pdf->SetTitle('PDF');
$pdf->SetSubject('PDF');
$pdf->SetKeywords('PDF');
// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();
// Set some content to print

$pdf->Image('imagenes/logo_restaurante.gif',20, 20, 20, 25, '', '', 'T', false, 72, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);

$pdf->SetXY(20, 42);
$pdf->writeHTML($nombre_restaurante,'<br>');
$pdf->SetXY(20, 47);
$pdf->writeHTML($direccion_restaurante,'<br>');
$pdf->SetXY(20, 52);
$pdf->writeHTML($ciudad_restaurante,'<br>');
$pdf->SetXY(130, 12);
$pdf->writeHTML("Orden ".$_SESSION['pedido'],'<br>');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetXY(130, 17);
$pdf->writeHTML("Fecha/Hora inicio: ",'<br>');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->SetXY(130, 22);
$pdf->writeHTML(recuperar_fecha_pedido($_SESSION['pedido']),'<br>');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetXY(130, 27);
$pdf->writeHTML("Le atendió: ",'<br>');
$pdf->SetXY(130, 32);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->writeHTML(recuperar_nombre_usuario(recuperar_atendio_pedido($_SESSION['pedido'])),'<br>');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetXY(130, 37);
$pdf->writeHTML("Mesa: ",'<br>');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->SetXY(130, 42);
$pdf->writeHTML(recuperar_nombre_mesa(recuperar_mesa_pedido($_SESSION['pedido'])),'<br>');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","XXX");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $pdf->SetXY(15, 72);
  $x= 72;
  $nombre_plato ="";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tb_lineas_comanda WHERE id_pedido = '".$_SESSION['pedido']."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  $nombre_plato .=  "  ".recuperar_nombre_plato($row['plato_pedido'])."";


}

$pdf->writeHTML($nombre_plato, true, 0, true, 0);
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('', 'I');
//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+

?>
```

Comment: post the `recuperar_nombre_plato()` function

Comment: How can we possibly diagnose this problem without the code for recuperar_nombre_plato?

Comment: @Dagon, I have included the function in my question. Thank you

Comment: @EdCottrell,  I have included the function in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  cannot return more than one thing from a function, so a return statement in a loop makes no sense. So build a temporary string in this loop and then return that string.

```
function recuperar_nombre_plato ($recibido) {
    $hostname = 'XXX';
    $username = 'XXX';
    $password = 'XXX';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXX", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_platos WHERE id_plato = '".$recibido."'";
        $str = '';
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
            $str .= $row['nombre_plato'];
        }
        return $str;

        // nothing happens after a return so this will never get run
        //$dbh = null;  
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Or if the query can only return one row because `id_plato` is a unique key then change the code to reflect that fact.

```
function recuperar_nombre_plato ($recibido) {
    $hostname = 'XXX';
    $username = 'XXX';
    $password = 'XXX';

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXX", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_platos WHERE id_plato = '".$recibido."'";

        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row['nombre_plato'];

        // nothing happens after a return so this will never get run
        //$dbh = null;  
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Also in your main function as you are building a text string from multiple calls to `recuperar_nombre_plato()` do you not want to move the call to `$pdf->writeHTML` outside the loop. And the initialization of `$nombre_plato` before the loop like this :-

```
$nombre_plato ="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $nombre_plato .= "  ".recuperar_nombre_plato($row['plato_pedido']);
}
$pdf->writeHTML($nombre_plato, true, 0, true, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly, I have changed my code as you propose. Using your first proposal, the output remains blank. Using your second proposal, I get an exception: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Comment: No, it only throws one row, but as I told in my question, I am using this function on other parts of my project and as far as I know, it is working fine as it is...

Comment: Rigss, are you sure that the issue is due to the function? I guess it has to do more with the way TCPDF works...but not sure...I am not an expert.

Comment: Your new edited version throws no error, but the output remains blank, Thank you in any case, your proposal for the function is better than mine.

Comment: Thank you, the output remains blank.

Comment: Yes Riggs, echoing $nombre_plato shows the expecting output, but throws  an exception when generating the PDF file...now I am sure that the issue is due to the $pdf->writeHTML($nombre_plato, true, 0, true, 0);

Comment: I will keep on searching the TCPDF docs, but there is no much information.

Comment: Thank you for your time and kindness....I will accept  your answer as there are no other proposals...

Comment: What exception is it generating?

Comment: When adding the echo line: Café espresso Café espresso Café espresso Café espresso 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/solinpro/public_html/restappxxireloaded/Invoice.php:145) in /home/solinpro/public_html/restappxxireloaded/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7624
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Comment: Yea, remove all echo / print etc that would generate anything that goes to the browser before you do the call to `$pdf->...` That includes any blank line before the `<?php` in your source code

Comment: Without adding the echo line, the rest of the generated PDF file is OK, only the part where the query output should appear, remains blank

Comment: Riggs, I have just included the complete source code and the current PDF output, so you have all info and may be you can find a solution...thank you

Comment: Do any of those included files contain a blank line or some `echo` or `print`